# How does a spinning black hole affect space-time compared to a non-spinning black hole?

Tags: black-hole, space-time, rotation

I often see questions on this site that only apply to non-spinning black holes and often wonder how the answer would be different for a spinning black hole.  As the title says, what are the major differences between the behavior of spinning and non-spinning black holes, especially when it comes to the effect on space-time?

Comment: This sounds a bit too broad question. Have you done some basic research on the topic on your own, eg https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric? If so, please refine the question to be more specific

Comment: This would be an essay on the differences between the Schwarzschild and Kerr metrics.

Comment: You could look at chapters 17 and onward of http://www.eftaylor.com/exploringblackholes/

Comment: @tuomas Indeed I have done some research but there is no similar question on this site so I figured that I should ask one!